# Incompatible Peer Dependency during Angular update

Tags: angular

I get the following peer dependency errors when trying to update Angular 8.3.29 to Angular 9.0. What is the difference between the version that it "requires" vs "would install"? And is it referring to ng-bootstrap or angular?

[image: peer dependencies]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like ng-bootstrap currently requires Angular ^7, but Angular ^9 is going to be installed.
Likely there is a set of versions of ng-bootstrap that support Angular 9.

To help you get there you can add `--force` to your `ng update` command to tell it to keep going. Then you can look at what version of ng-bootstrap you should update to and if there are any changes you need to put in for that. You can find ng-bootstraps CHANGELOG [here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)